# The limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \exp(-1+\exp(-2+\exp(-3+\cdots\exp(-n) \cdots)))$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Does the following limit exist ?
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-1+\exp(-2+\exp(-3+\cdots\exp(-n)\cdots)))$$

If yes, can it be expressed in a closed form ?

PARI shows the following numerical value :

```
n=-100;x=exp(n);while(n<-1,n=n+1;x=exp(x+n));print(x)
```

$0.4241685586940448516119410516$

Within this precision, $-200$ yields the same value.

Comment: @adobe how did you manage to get n->oo under "lim" ?

Comment: There are three ways, I will cite only 2:
 - Displaystyle for *inline* mode by putting `\displaystyle` before typing the other mathematical expressions. Ex: `$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to\0}$` will render as: $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}$.
 - Writing mathematical expressions in non inline mode that is `$$ <- math expression -> $$` will automatically put $n\to\infty$ under $\lim$. Ex: `$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$` will be rendered as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$.

Comment: It converges rapidly.  Even for $n=-5$ the first $9$ places are correct in Excel

Comment: @Peter You're very welcome.

Comment: What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-2+\exp(-3+\ldots\exp(-n)...)))$$?Is it equal to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-1+\exp(-2+\exp(-3+\ldots\exp(-n)...)))$$?

Comment: @Manasi, obviously no, because if the upper line is $A$ then the lower line is $exp(-1+A)$, and due to convexity of $exp$ equality is impossible for $A\ne 0$.

Comment: Okay, the first limit is $ A > 0 $ and the second limit is $exp(-1 + A)> 0$ Both are $ > 0$ due to convexity but I did not get your reason.

Comment: Here's a a half-hearted attempt to find the value of the limit, in the spirit of Ramanujan's nested square-roots: Define $F(x)=\exp(-1+x+\exp(-2+x+\exp(-3+\cdots)))$ to be the limit of the above expression with an extra parameter $x$. Then $\exp(F(x-1)+x-1)=F(x)$. Does anyone see a way to solve this functional equation? You could *almost* use Lambert's W function on this if we had $F(x)$ in the exponential instead.

Comment: The answer seems to be the smallest number $A$ such that the function $$f(n) = \underbrace{\ln(\ln(\cdots\ln(A}_{\text{n times}}+1)+2)+\cdots)+n-1) + n$$ has no imaginary part as $n \to \infty$

Comment: This can be written as $e^{-1} \mathop{\large \textrm E}_{n=2}^{\infty} e^{e^{-n}}$, where $\mathop{\large \textrm E}_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n = a_k^{a_{k+1}^{a_{k+2}^{\cdots}}}$.  This notation was introduced by Barrow in the paper *Infinite exponentials*, [The American Mathematical Monthly , Vol. 43, No. 3 (Mar., 1936), pp. 150-160](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2300357).

Comment: @user93957 I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit exists because the sequence is monotonic and bounded, although I don't know yet what the limit is. Let's denote this sequence $E_n$.

The sequence is monotonic because $-n+\exp(-(n+1))>-n$, therefore $\exp(-n)+\exp(-(n+1)))>\exp(-n)$, therefore $\exp(-(n-1)+\exp(-n)+\exp(-(n+1))))>\exp(-(n-1)+\exp(-n))$, etc, until you get $E_{n+1}>E_n$.

The sequence is bounded because $-n+\exp(\text{negative number})<0$, therefore $E_n<\exp(0)=1$.

By monotone convergence theorem $E_n$ converges.